# PHP mail() fails if the subject doesn't contain "Subject: "

Tags: php

If I send mail using the PHP mail() function, the mail will not go through unless I prepend the word "Subject: "  to the subject line.

Here's the code:

```
 $from = "shamsneed@gmail.com";
 $subject = urldecode($_GET['theSubj']) . "\r\n";
 $body =  "Here ya go now\r\n";
 $Header = "From: $from \r\n";

 $retval = mail($advertisersEmail, $subject, $body, $Header);
```

EDIT: the 'retval' is always "1" even when the recipient doesn't get the email.

I even tried this:

```
 $Header .= "Subject: $subject";
```

None of the above sends an email successfully to the recipient.

I've tried a lot of permutations on the above code: removing all the "\r", removing all the "\r\n", not using urldecode().

The only way I can get an email sent is if I change the "subject" to this:

```
 $subject = "Subject: " . urldecode($_GET['theSubj']) . "\r\n";
```

The problem with this is, the word "Subject: "  is showing up in the recipient's email they receive from our site and I don't want that.  I've checked the PHP manual for mail and it says nothing about needing to add "Subject:"  to the passed-in subject in the 2nd parameter to mail().

What am I missing here?

Comment: $from value will be in quotes? isn't it? you  wrote it accedently or it is like that?

Comment: fixed that, the actual code is correct, I just typed it wrong initially above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the mail address is not in quotes, try fixing that first.

Are you on a shared hosting or is this a private server? If it's a shared hosting, try contacting them. I have send a lot of mails via PHP and never endured this problem.

If all is not working, try sending your mail via SMTP. You can use libraries like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/phpmailer/phpmailer) to make your life easier.

Comment: I'm on shared hosting.  I suspect you might be right, my hosting provider (1and1) may have a PHP setting wrong in an .ini file somewhere....